# What are the effects of rolling updates TiDB？

Tags: tidb

What are the effects of rolling updates TiDB？ If it will impact production env?
When do the TiKV leader's transfer to other TiKV, how much time it will take?
I have tried to find from PingCAP documents, I can't find the result.

Answer (score 0):

when you apply rolling updates to the TiDB services, the running application is not affected. If the Pump or Drainer service is involved in the cluster, it is recommended to stop Drainer before rolling updates. When you upgrade TiDB, Pump is also upgraded. The TiKV leader transfers to some other TiKV before this TiKV binary roll up, and this process won't keep long time, it may be several seconds.
More details pls check the doc https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/upgrade-tidb-using-tiup